# Magento 2.3. How to create image upload field in an admin form

Tags: magento2.3, adminform

I want to discribe How I have created image upload field in an admin form.

My module's name is Paracrab\Banners

1. Firstly You should add field in Paracrab/Banners/view/adminhtml/ui_component/name_name_form.xml

> `<field name="image" sortOrder="30" formElement="imageUploader">
>               <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
>                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
>                       <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
>                   </item>
>               </argument>
>               <settings>
>                   <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
>                   <dataType>string</dataType>
>                   <label translate="true">Banner Image</label>
>                   <visible>true</visible>
>                   <required>false</required>
>               </settings>
>               <formElements>
>                   <imageUploader>
>                       <settings>
>                           <required>false</required>
>                           <uploaderConfig>
>                               <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="banner/banner/upload"/>
>                           </uploaderConfig>
>                           <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
>                           <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>paracrab/image</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
>                           <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
>                           <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
>                       </settings>
>                   </imageUploader>
>               </formElements>
>           </field>`

`name="image"`it is name field in database.

2. Will create admin Controller and Action

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Paracrab\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner;
>
> use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
>
> class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
> {
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader
>      */
>     protected $imageUploader;
>
>
>     public function __construct(
>         \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
>         \Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
>     ) {
>         parent::__construct($context);
>         $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
>      */
>     public function execute()
>     {
>         $imageId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'image');
>
>         try {
>             $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageId);
>         } catch (\Exception $e) {
>             $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
>         }
>         return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
>     }
> }
> ```

Did you notice  `\Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader` in `__construct` ? 
You need create this class.

3. Create `Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader` class

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Paracrab\Banners\Model;
>
>
> class ImageUploader
> {
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
>      */
>     protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
>      */
>     protected $mediaDirectory;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
>      */
>     private $uploaderFactory;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
>      */
>     protected $storeManager;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
>      */
>     protected $logger;
>
>     /**
>      * @var
>      */
>     protected $baseTmpPath;
>
>     /**
>      * @var
>      */
>     protected $basePath;
>
>     /**
>      * @var
>      */
>     protected $allowedExtensions;
>
>     /**
>      * @var array
>      */
>     private $allowedMimeTypes;
>
>     /**
>      * ImageUploader constructor.
>      * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
>      * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
>      * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
>      * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
>      * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
>      * @param $baseTmpPath
>      * @param $basePath
>      * @param $allowedExtensions
>      * @param array $allowedMimeTypes
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
>      */
>     public function __construct(
>         \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
>         \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
>         \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
>         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
>         \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
>         $baseTmpPath,
>         $basePath,
>         $allowedExtensions,
>         $allowedMimeTypes = []
>     ) {
>         $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
>         $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
>         $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
>         $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
>         $this->logger = $logger;
>         $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
>         $this->basePath = $basePath;
>         $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
>         $this->allowedMimeTypes = $allowedMimeTypes;
>     }
>
>
>     /**
>      * @param $baseTmpPath
>      */
>     public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
>     {
>         $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
>     }
>
>
>     /**
>      * @param $basePath
>      */
>     public function setBasePath($basePath)
>     {
>         $this->basePath = $basePath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $allowedExtensions
>      */
>     public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
>     {
>         $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function getBaseTmpPath()
>     {
>         return $this->baseTmpPath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function getBasePath()
>     {
>         return $this->basePath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function getAllowedExtensions()
>     {
>         return $this->allowedExtensions;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $path
>      * @param $imageName
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
>     {
>         return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $imageName
>      * @return mixed
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
>      */
>     public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
>     {
>         $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
>         $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
>
>         $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
>         $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
>
>         try {
>             $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
>                 $baseTmpImagePath,
>                 $baseImagePath
>             );
>             $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
>                 $baseTmpImagePath,
>                 $baseImagePath
>             );
>         } catch (\Exception $e) {
>             throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
>                 __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
>             );
>         }
>
>         return $imageName;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $fileId
>      * @return array
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
>      */
>     public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
>     {
>         $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
>
>         /** @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader $uploader */
>         $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
>         $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
>         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
>         if (!$uploader->checkMimeType($this->allowedMimeTypes)) {
>             throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('File validation failed.'));
>         }
>         $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
>
>         unset($result['path']);
>
>         if (!$result) {
>             throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
>                 __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
>             );
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
>          */
>         $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
>         $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
>                 ->getStore()
>                 ->getBaseUrl(
>                     \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
>                 ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
>         $result['name'] = $result['file'];
>
>         if (isset($result['file'])) {
>             try {
>                 $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
>                 $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
>             } catch (\Exception $e) {
>                 $this->logger->critical($e);
>                 throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
>                     __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
>                 );
>             }
>         }
>
>         return $result;
>     }
> }
> ```

This class was copied from

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php
```

4. You need create `virtualType` for this class in `etc/di.xml` with parameters

> ```
>  <virtualType name="Paracrab\Banners\ImageUploader" type="Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader">
>         <arguments>
>             <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">paracrab/tmp/image</argument>
>             <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">paracrab/image</argument>
>             <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
>                 <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
>                 <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
>                 <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
>                 <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
>             </argument>
>             <argument name="allowedMimeTypes" xsi:type="array">
>                 <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
>                 <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
>                 <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
>                 <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
>             </argument>
>         </arguments>
>     </virtualType>
>     <type name="Paracrab\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner\Upload">
>         <arguments>
>             <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Paracrab\Banners\ImageUploader</argument>
>         </arguments>
>     </type>
>     <type name="Paracrab\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Banners\Save">
>         <arguments>
>             <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Paracrab\Banners\ImageUploader</argument>
>         </arguments>
>     </type>
> ```

5. Also You should create class `Paracrab/Banners/Model/Banner/FileInfo.php`

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner;
>
> use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
> use Magento\Framework\File\Mime;
> use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
> use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface;
>
> /**
>  * Class FileInfo
>  *
>  * Provides information about requested file
>  */
> class FileInfo
> {
>     /**
>      * Path in /pub/media directory
>      */
>     const ENTITY_MEDIA_PATH = 'paracrab/image';
>
>     /**
>      * @var Filesystem
>      */
>     private $filesystem;
>
>     /**
>      * @var Mime
>      */
>     private $mime;
>
>     /**
>      * @var WriteInterface
>      */
>     private $mediaDirectory;
>
>     /**
>      * @var ReadInterface
>      */
>     private $baseDirectory;
>
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
>      */
>     protected $_storeManager;
>
>     /**
>      * @param Filesystem $filesystem
>      * @param Mime $mime
>      */
>     public function __construct(
>         Filesystem $filesystem,
>         Mime $mime,
>         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
>     ) {
>         $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
>         $this->mime = $mime;
>         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get WriteInterface instance
>      *
>      * @return WriteInterface
>      */
>     public function getMediaDirectory()
>     {
>         if ($this->mediaDirectory === null) {
>             $this->mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
>         }
>         return $this->mediaDirectory;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get Base Directory read instance
>      *
>      * @return ReadInterface
>      */
>     private function getBaseDirectory()
>     {
>         if (!isset($this->baseDirectory)) {
>             $this->baseDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
>         }
>
>         return $this->baseDirectory;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Retrieve MIME type of requested file
>      *
>      * @param string $fileName
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getMimeType($fileName)
>     {
>         $filePath = $this->getFilePath($fileName);
>         $absoluteFilePath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getAbsolutePath($filePath);
>
>         $result = $this->mime->getMimeType($absoluteFilePath);
>         return $result;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $fileName
>      * @return string
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
>      */
>     public function getAbsolutePatch($fileName)
>     {
>
>         $absoluteFilePath = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
>         $absoluteFilePath .= $this->getFilePath($fileName);
>         return $absoluteFilePath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get file statistics data
>      *
>      * @param string $fileName
>      * @return array
>      */
>     public function getStat($fileName)
>     {
>         $filePath = $this->getFilePath($fileName);
>
>         $result = $this->getMediaDirectory()->stat($filePath);
>         return $result;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Check if the file exists
>      *
>      * @param string $fileName
>      * @return bool
>      */
>     public function isExist($fileName)
>     {
>         $filePath = $this->getFilePath($fileName);
>
>         $result = $this->getMediaDirectory()->isExist($filePath);
>         return $result;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Construct and return file subpath based on filename relative to media directory
>      *
>      * @param string $fileName
>      * @return string
>      */
>     private function getFilePath($fileName)
>     {
>         $filePath = ltrim($fileName, '/');
>
>         $mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath = $this->getMediaDirectoryPathRelativeToBaseDirectoryPath();
>         $isFileNameBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath = $this->isBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath($fileName);
>
>         // if the file is not using a relative path, it resides in the paracrab/image media directory
>         $fileIsInModuleMediaDir = !$isFileNameBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath;
>
>         if ($fileIsInModuleMediaDir) {
>             $filePath = self::ENTITY_MEDIA_PATH . '/' . $filePath;
>         } else {
>             $filePath = substr($filePath, strlen($mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath));
>         }
>
>         return $filePath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Checks for whether $fileName string begins with media directory path
>      *
>      * @param string $fileName
>      * @return bool
>      */
>     public function isBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath($fileName)
>     {
>         $filePath = ltrim($fileName, '/');
>
>         $mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath = $this->getMediaDirectoryPathRelativeToBaseDirectoryPath();
>         $isFileNameBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath = strpos($filePath, $mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath) === 0;
>
>         return $isFileNameBeginsWithMediaDirectoryPath;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get media directory subpath relative to base directory path
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     private function getMediaDirectoryPathRelativeToBaseDirectoryPath()
>     {
>         $baseDirectoryPath = $this->getBaseDirectory()->getAbsolutePath();
>         $mediaDirectoryPath = $this->getMediaDirectory()->getAbsolutePath();
>
>         $mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath = substr($mediaDirectoryPath, strlen($baseDirectoryPath));
>
>         return $mediaDirectoryRelativeSubpath;
>     }
> }
> ```

This class similar this `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php`

6. You have `DataProvider` for displaing form in whole. This is code my  `DataProvider` class

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner;
>
> use Paracrab\Banners\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory as BannerCollectionFactory;
> use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
> use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Api\BannerRepositoryInterface;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner\FileInfo;
>
> class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\ModifierPoolDataProvider
> {
>     /**
>      * @var \Paracrab\Banners\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\Collection
>      */
>     protected $collection;
>
>     /**
>      * @var DataPersistorInterface
>      */
>     protected $dataPersistor;
>
>     /**
>      * @var
>      */
>     protected $loadedData;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
>      */
>     protected $request;
>
>     /**
>      * @var BannerRepositoryInterface
>      */
>     protected $bannerRepository;
>
>     /**
>      * @var \Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner\FileInfo
>      */
>     protected $fileInfo;
>
>     /**
>      * DataProvider constructor.
>      * @param $name
>      * @param $primaryFieldName
>      * @param $requestFieldName
>      * @param BannerCollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory
>      * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
>      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
>      * @param BannerRepositoryInterface $bannerRepository
>      * @param \Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner\FileInfo $fileInfo
>      * @param array $meta
>      * @param array $data
>      * @param PoolInterface|null $pool
>      */
>     public function __construct(
>         $name,
>         $primaryFieldName,
>         $requestFieldName,
>         BannerCollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,
>         DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
>         \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
>         BannerRepositoryInterface $bannerRepository,
>         FileInfo $fileInfo,
>         array $meta = [],
>         array $data = [],
>         PoolInterface $pool = null
>     ) {
>         $this->collection = $pageCollectionFactory->create();
>         $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
>         $this->request = $request;
>         $this->bannerRepository = $bannerRepository;
>         $this->fileInfo = $fileInfo;
>         parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data, $pool);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return array
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
>      */
>     public function getData()
>     {
>         if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
>             return $this->loadedData;
>         }
>
>         $bannerId = $this->request->getParam('banner_id');
>
>         if($bannerId) {
>             $item = $this->bannerRepository->getById($bannerId);
>             $fileName = $item->getData('image');
>
>             if($this->fileInfo->isExist($fileName) && $fileName !== '') {
>                 $stat = $this->fileInfo->getStat($fileName);
>                 $image = [
>                     0 => [
>                       'name' =>  basename($fileName),
>                       'url' => $this->fileInfo->getAbsolutePatch($fileName),
>                       'size' => isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0,
>                       'type' => $this->fileInfo->getMimeType($fileName)
>                     ]
>                 ];
>
>                 $item->setData('image', $image);
>
>             }
>
>             $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $item->getData();
>         }
>
>         $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('paracrab_banner');
>
>         if (!empty($data)) {
>             $page = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
>             $page->setData($data);
>             $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
>             $this->dataPersistor->clear('paracrab_banner');
>         }
>
>         return $this->loadedData;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> 7. You have `Action` for saving data from form. This is how my Action look like
>
> ```
> <?php
> namespace Paracrab\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Banners;
>
> use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
> use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
> use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Model\Banner;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Model\BannerFactory;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Api\BannerRepositoryInterface;
> use Paracrab\Banners\Model\ImageUploader;
>
> class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
> {
>     /**
>      * @var DataPersistorInterface
>      */
>     protected $dataPersistor;
>
>     /**
>      * @var BannerFactory
>      */
>     private $bannerFactory;
>
>     /**
>      * @var BannerRepositoryInterface
>      */
>     private $bannerRepository;
>
>     /**
>      * @var ImageUploader
>      */
>     private $imageUploader;
>
>
>     /**
>      * Save constructor.
>      * @param Context $context
>      * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
>      * @param BannerFactory $bannerFactory
>      * @param BannerRepositoryInterface $bannerRepository
>      * @param ImageUploader $imageUploader
>      */
>     public function __construct
>     (
>         Context $context,
>         DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
>         BannerFactory $bannerFactory,
>         BannerRepositoryInterface $bannerRepository,
>         ImageUploader $imageUploader
>     )
>     {
>         $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
>         $this->bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
>         $this->bannerRepository = $bannerRepository;
>         $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
>          parent::__construct($context);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
>      */
>     public function execute()
>     {
>         $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
>         $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
>
>         if ($data) {
>             if (isset($data['status']) && $data['status'] === 'true') {
>                 $data['status'] = Banner::STATUS_ENABLED;
>             }
>             if (empty($data['banner_id'])) {
>                 $data['banner_id'] = null;
>             }
>
>             if(isset($data['image'])) {
>                 $fileName = $data['image'][0]['name'];
>                 $data['image'] = $fileName;
>                 $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($fileName);
>             } else {
>                 $data['image'] = '';
>             }
>
>             $model = $this->bannerFactory->create();
>
>             $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id');
>             if ($id) {
>                 try {
>                     $model = $this->bannerRepository->getById($id);
>                 } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
>                     $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This banner no longer exists.'));
>                     return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
>                 }
>             }
>
>             $model->setData($data);
>
>             try {
>                 $this->bannerRepository->save($model);
>                 $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the banner.'));
>                 $this->dataPersistor->clear('paracrab_banner');
>                 return $this->processBlockReturn($model, $data, $resultRedirect);
>             } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
>                 $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
>             } catch (\Exception $e) {
>                 $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the banner.'));
>             }
>
>             $this->dataPersistor->set('paracrab_banner', $data);
>             return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $id]);
>         }
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param $model
>      * @param $data
>      * @param $resultRedirect
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     private function processBlockReturn($model, $data, $resultRedirect)
>     {
>         $redirect = $data['back'] ?? 'close';
>
>         if ($redirect ==='continue') {
>             $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $model->getId()]);
>         } else if ($redirect === 'close') {
>             $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
>         }
>         return $resultRedirect;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

8. Create directories in `pub/media` like `paracrab/images` and `paracrab/tmp/images`

Answer (score 0):

Upload the Custom image at Category

1. Create a InstallData.php file at vendor\Module\Setup and add the below code into the InstallData.php

Create a InstallData.php file on location vendor\Module\Setup

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
    
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
    
    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * EAV setup factory.
         *
         * @var EavSetupFactory
         */
        private $_eavSetupFactory;
        protected $categorySetupFactory;
    
        /**
         * Init.
         *
         * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
        {
            $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
            $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         *
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context
        ) {
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
            $setup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_catimg', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Custom category image',
                    'input' => 'image',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 9,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

2. Create a category_form.xml file into vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component and write down the below code
   In this file, you have to change the field name as per your attribute code and url as per your controller
   like path="module/category_catimg/upload"/ there are module is the route.xml in etc/adminhtml/route.xml name

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="content">
            <field name="custom_catimg">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                        <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/category_catimg/upload"/>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

3. Now add the below  code into the Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
        <type name="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
        <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
                <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
                <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Category\DataProvider" />
```

4. Create Upload.php file into Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image and write down the below code

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    
    /**
     * Agorae Adminhtml Category Image Upload Controller
     */
    class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
         * Image uploader
         *
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
         */
        protected $imageUploader;
    
        /**
         * Uploader factory
         *
         * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
         */
        private $uploaderFactory;
    
        /**
         * Media directory object (writable).
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
         */
        protected $mediaDirectory;
    
        /**
         * Store manager
         *
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;
    
        /**
         * Core file storage database
         *
         * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
         */
        protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    
        /**
         * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
         */
        protected $logger;
    
        /**
         * Upload constructor.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
            $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
            $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    
        /**
         * Check admin permissions for this controller
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        protected function _isAllowed()
        {
            return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::category');
        }
    
        /**
         * Upload file controller action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            try {
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('custom_catimg');
                $result['cookie'] = [
                    'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                    'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                    'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                    'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                    'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
                ];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
            }
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
        }
    }
```

5. Create Upload.php file on location Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    
    /**
     * Agorae Adminhtml Category Image Upload Controller
     */
    class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
         * Image uploader
         *
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
         */
        protected $imageUploader;
    
        /**
         * Uploader factory
         *
         * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
         */
        private $uploaderFactory;
    
        /**
         * Media directory object (writable).
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
         */
        protected $mediaDirectory;
    
        /**
         * Store manager
         *
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;
    
        /**
         * Core file storage database
         *
         * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
         */
        protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    
        /**
         * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
         */
        protected $logger;
    
        /**
         * Upload constructor.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
            $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
            $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    
        /**
         * Check admin permissions for this controller
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        protected function _isAllowed()
        {
            return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::category');
        }
    
        /**
         * Upload file controller action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            try {
                $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('custom_catimg');
                $result['cookie'] = [
                    'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                    'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                    'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                    'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                    'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
                ];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
            }
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
        }
    }
```

6. Create DataProvider.php file on location Vendor\Module\Model\Category and write down the below code

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Category;
     
    class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider
    {
     
        protected function getFieldsMap()
        {
            $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
            $fields['content'][] = 'custom_catimg'; // custom image field
            
            return $fields;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to the below Solution
https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upload-image-or-file-in-custom-module-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/